# 100 columns vs Array of length 100

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 100+ values corresponding to each row, so I'm exploring different ways to store them.

Without any indexes, would I lose anything if I store these 100 values in an `integer[]` column in postgresql? As compared to storing them in separate columns.

Plus, since we can add indexes to array elemnets,

`CREATE INDEX test_index on test ((foo[1]));`

Would there be a performance difference queries using such an index as compared to regular index on a column?

As far as I've read, this performance difference would come into picture in arrays with variable length elements; but I'm not sure about fixed length ones.

Comment: What about normalization and putting these values in a different table? 100+ values of the same type, sounds like a modeling problem.

Comment: Nope, they're basically various different metrics for a particular request to a webserver.

Comment: When all values have a different meaning, they should not be in the same array. If you want a single field for all these values, maybe json is the right datatype for you. It can also be indexed in version 9.4 (will be released soon) and above.

Comment: Why shouldn't they be in the same array? If I'm storing anywhere from 100 to 200 metrics per request; how does storing them as columns prove to be a better model? Genuinely would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for the lazy way.
If you need to store 100 and more values as array, it is ok, if it has sense has array for your application, your data.

If you need to query for a specific element of the array, then this design is not good, regardless of performances, and you must use columns. This will help you in the moment you must delete a "column" in the middle or redesign it.

Anyway, as wrote by Frank in comments, if values are all same type, consider to model them to another table (if also the meaning is the same).

Comment: "*If you need to query for a specific element of the array, then this design is not good*" - where is the difference between writing `where foo_7 = 42` and `where foo[7] = 42`. You can create an index for both expressions and if you need to index for all columns you wind up with the same number of indexes in both solutions. *If*(!) there is a valid reason for so many columns, I actually think that using an array is more flexible

Comment: Just a design consideration. Imagine the moment you have to drop a column. With the array solution, where index is on a position, all index will be recalculated.
For performances? I agree, it is ok.